# executable built with PyInstaller no longer uses GPU acceleration

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, pyinstaller, yolo

I'm working on an object detection project using YOLOv4-tiny and only OpenCV. I've successfully improved performance by utilizing my integrated GPU (Intel HD 520) on my HP EliteBook 840 G3 with the following code:

```
self.net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(CONFIG, WEIGHTS)
cv2.dnn.DNN_CLEAR_FORWARD = 1
cv2.dnn.DNN_CLEAR_BACKWARD = 1
cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(True)
self.net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
self.net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_OPENCL)
self.model.setInputParams(size=(416, 416), scale=1/255)
```

The performance is satisfactory on my laptop, and I've created an executable using PyInstaller. However, when I run the executable on other laptops, it doesn't work on laptops with integrated GPUs. Sometimes it works on laptops with dedicated GPUs (I observed dedicated GPU is being utilized), but the performance improvement is not observed.

**Questions:**

How can I ensure that my OpenCV-based (executable) object detection project utilizes the integrated GPU on other laptops, especially those with integrated GPUs?

Is there a way to specify whether the application should use the integrated or dedicated GPU for improved performance consistently?

Are there any additional steps or configurations I need to consider when creating an executable to ensure compatibility with different GPU setups?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!